# mkdir(): Permission denied Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running the following script for an image upload in a server and getting the following error while it works perfectly on the localhost.

**Code**

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
$logicpath = 'userdp/' . $user_id . '/';
$pubpath = 'userdp/' . $user_id . '/' . $dpFile;
$path = '/userdp/' . $user_id . '/' . $dpFile;

if (!file_exists($logicpath)) {
     mkdir($logicpath, 0777, true);
}
```

**Error**

> ErrorException in UploadController.php line 605: mkdir(): Permission
>   denied
>
> at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'mkdir(): Permission denied',
>   '/var/www/html/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/UploadController.php',
>   '605', array('dp' => object(UploadedFile), 'ext' => 'jpg', 'img' =>
>   object(Image), 'mime' => 'image/jpeg', 'width' => '200', 'height' =>
>   '200', 'fileSize' => '17152', 'dpFile' =>
>   'f12f298ab18d58a59c4ed8a589cd1cdc.jpg', 'user_id' => '1', 'logicpath'
>   => 'userdp/1/', 'pubpath' => 'userdp/1/f12f298ab18d58a59c4ed8a589cd1cdc.jpg', 'path' =>
>   '/userdp/1/f12f298ab18d58a59c4ed8a589cd1cdc.jpg'))

I tried `chmod 777 public` and restarted the server. But it didn't work.

Comment: You should use 755 not 777.

Comment: Never ever give 777 permission to your root folder. Its security leak for profession hackers. Please try to bind tight security rules and assign only needed permissions / rights to the group / user.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

You have to perform chmod recursively to make sure all subdirectories also carry the same permissions. Try running this instead:

```
chmod -R 777
```

Now while this will fix your issue, you should definitely read up on the problems that arise with setting the above permissions as this link posted in comments below shows. Ill post here as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11271632/2790481

EDIT: This should only be done within the Laravel storage dir within `/var/www/html/laravel/storage`, for example and never be done at the system level. I forgot to mention that originally, hence all the downvotes.

Comment: Careful with this command: [How will a server become vulnerable with chmod 777](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11271632/2790481)

Comment: This will likely break your entire system

Comment: This command makes the whole server vulnerable. Please don't use this command.

Comment: Your code will work for sure after giving 777 permissions but it makes server vulnerable for attacks.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/yoursite/public
```

Answer (score 6):

**ERROR:**

```
  [ErrorException]            
  mkdir(): Permission denied
```

If you are creating Project in `/WWW` folder and if you are encountering the above error, then try using following commands, It worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
```

After Running this, Try Creating Project again.

```
cd /var/www

composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname "5.6.*"
```

since i'm using laravel 5.6 i have specified version while creating Project.

Comment: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www worked for me ! thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I have found a very interesting solution to this problem. Just put "." sign like this example. It works for me.

```
$destinationPath = "./public/uploads"; // upload path
    if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
      mkdir($destinationPath, 0755, true);
    }
    $request->sub_category_attr_value->move($destinationPath, $picName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to move the uploaded file a folder in the root of your server. Make sure you get the absolute path right.

```
$logicpath = public_path() . '/userdp/' . $user_id . '/';
```

Comment: You also need to chmod the the `userdp` recursively: `chmod -R 755 public/userdp`

Answer (score 2):

Running `chmod -R 777` may not work and should never be used for security reasons, this has always been a warning.

=> This will work of for you as stated above by @bokino12

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/yoursite/public`

=> if for some reason it doesn't work, that could be that the present user doesn't have permission over the directory, try

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/yoursite/public`

This will assign the current user as the owner of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont change mode to 777 as it may cause your some serious security issues. Rather try using these commands for changing permission of the folder.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
chmod -R 755 </userdp> Your upload folder path
```

Try uploading - It will work - In case it fails try

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
$logicpath = '/userdp/' . $user_id . '/';
$pubpath = 'userdp/' . $user_id . '/' . $dpFile;
$path = '/userdp/' . $user_id . '/' . $dpFile;

if (!file_exists($logicpath)) {
     mkdir($logicpath, 0755, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, go into your laravel project, make your public directory writable.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 public
```

Answer (score -7):

> I tried chmod 777 public and restarted the server. But it didn't work.

Be sure you use the CHMOD recursively and with administrator permissions (if you can)

```
SUDO CHMOD -R 777 /var/www/html/laravel/
```

Regards

Comment: This command makes the whole server vulnerable. Please don't use this command.