# Laravel storage folders and their permissions

Tags: php, laravel

I need to create a specific folder inside a folder already created by `$file->store()`. I however lack the permissions I need to set for Laravel to correctly work with it some later time. Is it only this?:

```
mkdir($dir, 0777, ...)
```

It's just that whenever I read `777` something tells me this ain't right. So, may it be `755` for Laravel? Running under Windows.

Comment: under windows (for dev) you don't need to set permission, however, I reccomended you never give 777 permission for folder. finally try to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443175/mkdir-permission-denied-laravel

Comment: @LorenzoBerti the production server will also run under Windows (Server 2016).

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/yoursite/public

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/yoursite/storage