# PHP Slim throws Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, slim

I'm trying to deploy a RESTful web application which was developed in a local machine. The same code works perfectly in the local XAMPP server but fails to load upon uploading into a remote Linux server.

Here'e the **.htaccess file**,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Since it doesn't works, I've also tried with the small modification,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /slim/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I'm still getting error 500. Seems like the remote server is preventing the scripts or its files from getting executed. This is absolutely strange because the same codes works perfectly in local server. Any kind of help or suggestion would be realty appreciated.

The file permission for the file is also set to **777** (read, write, execute)

Current PHP version in remote server is **PHP V5.6**

Comment: If you get an error, please show us the log entry in the error.log.

Comment: On a 500 error, *always* inspect the webserver log. If you don't have access to it directly, ask your sysadmin/hosting provider to look into it for you.

Comment: Also, **never** use chmod 777. See [How will a server become vulnerable with chmod 777?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271596/how-will-a-server-become-vulnerable-with-chmod-777)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using suphp on your server and you have setup 777 permission for your all files and that is the reason you are facing this issues. Please change you all file permission to 644 and folder permission to 755 and check your domain URL.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't check the file permissions until I read this!!! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run your PHP slim app on live server e.g IONOS servers,
there are two things you need to sort out: 
**1. The webserver:** 
Create a .htaccess file in /var/www/html/myapp (root directory path)
where myapp directory stores all your slim app files.

> RewriteEngine On 
> RewriteBase /myapp 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

The key thing here is the RewriteBase directive which must be set.
**2. Your Slim 4 app config** 
In your index.php, add:

```
$app->setBasePath('/myapp');
```

Viola!

Follow link for detailed explanation https://akrabat.com/running-slim-4-in-a-subdirectory/#the-web-server-apache