# PHP - how to copy a file using a page like this?

Tags: php

[this is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EdDo.jpg) I'm trying to fix the copy function does not run. This my code:

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" ) {

    copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "php5/image" ) or die( "Could not copy file!");

} else {
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name']; ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size']; ?> bytes
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type']; ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Why it doesn't work? How to fix it?

I'm getting

> Warning: copy(feel_like_doraemon.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: show your upload form

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Okay, the problem has been fixed :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading files you should use `move_uploaded_file` to actually store the file in your chosen directory. Also, using a full path rather than a relative path has always worked better for me - change the applicable line to suit your environment.

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ){
    try{
        $obj=$_FILES['file'];
        $name=$obj['name'];
        $tmp=$obj['tmp_name'];

        $dir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php5/image';
        if( !realpath( $dir ) )throw new Exception( sprintf( 'unable to find target directory %s', $dir ) );

        $target="{$dir}/{$name}";

        if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target ) ){
            /* OK */
            @unlink( $tmp );
        } else {
            /* error */
        }
    }catch(Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
}


?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uploading Complete</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name']; ?>
            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size']; ?> bytes
            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type']; ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't `move_uploaded_file` move the file out, which makes your call to `unlink` pointless? Suppressing errors with an `@` is never advisable.

Comment: Good stuff - you probably should make the above a little more resilient by adding additional checks to verify the type and size of the file before saving - but glad it works now for you

Comment: belt n braces... using the `@` before `unlink` suppresses any such error

Comment: @RamRaider If the system is so broken that `move_uploaded_file` fails you have much bigger problems to worry about. The additional call to `unlink` is absolutely useless, adds overhead, and potentially could hide a real error.

Comment: Okay i will try to upgrade my upload file :D

Answer (score 0):

As `['name']` is name of file and not path to file after upload instead of `['name']` try use  `['tmp_name']`

```
copy( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "php5/image" ) or die( "Could not copy file!");
```

Comment: run `print_r($_FILES)`, you will see it there.

Comment: @YohanesAdiP Don't use this method, use `move_uploaded_file`! This method is insecure, broken, and leaves temp files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is because uploaded files are not stored on the server using their original name, they are given a temp filename which is in the `tmp_name` index. Furthermore you should use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead of `copy` for security.

Also your destination path needs to exist.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you have to use move upload file function instead of copy.

```
Do as mentioned below.
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" ) {

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "php5/image/".$name)or die( "Could not copy file!");
    //copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "php5/image" ) or die( "Could not copy file!");

} else {

    die("No file specified!");

}
?>
```

Comment: do NOT advise people to give 777 permissions on directories! Learn about file permissions and how they work before you tell people this dangerous advice! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271596/how-will-a-server-become-vulnerable-with-chmod-777

Comment: but you have to use move upload file instead of copy it will solve your problem

Comment: I down voted you because of your ill advice, until you remove it the down vote stays.