# Executing commands via PHP exec on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, selenium-grid

I want to run a linux command via PHP exec() and my first command below executing in background at Ubuntu Server 22.04 perfectly -

```
<?php
$cmd = "java -jar /var/www/html/selenium-drivers/selenium-server-4.14.1.jar hub";
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
?>
```

But the very similar of my second command is not executing.

```
<?php
$cmd = "java -jar /var/www/html/selenium-drivers/selenium-server-4.14.1.jar node --port 5555 --selenium-manager true";
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
?>
```

I am unable to find out the reason why not working. Anybody please help?

Checked all necessay permissions of PHP and there is not issue of permissions. First command executing perfectly but the second is not.

Comment: try `$cmd = "nohup java -jar /var/www/html/selenium-drivers/selenium-server-4.14.1.jar node --port 5555 --selenium-manager true > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
exec($cmd);`

Comment: What are these commands supposed to do? What does the `node` argument mean for the Java program?

Comment: The node argument is used to registed a node in selenium grid at post 5555. Let me try the suggestion of @Adi

Comment: I can't speak to your specific command, but a very common problem is that the user account that PHP is running as doesn't have all of the paths setup the same as your account. As such, something like `java` by itself can cause a problem. You can fix this by setting up paths, or just by using absolute paths such as `/use/bin/java`

Comment: Yes. @ChrisHaas You are right. Let me try that too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas But why would it work for one java command but not the other? They're both running the same JAR file, only with different arguments.

Comment: @Barmar, I'll be honest and say that I initially included my comment just as a blanket catch-all for common problems. However, looking at the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/getting_started/#node) the `node` parameter says "During startup time, the Node will detect the available drivers that it can use from the System `PATH`", so that's my best guess

Comment: No luck till now. Tried a numerous methods and combinations of arguments.. but failed. Both the command running well at Terminal. As @Barmar said, one command is working via `PHP exec()` but another IS NOT, while both ranning same `JAR file`. I am still hangged and waiting some solution

Comment: After debugging with `shell_exec()` I found the issue related to permission. Getting error `Cache folder (/var/www/.cache/selenium) cannot be created: Permission denied (os error 13)`  Any clue to fix this permission issue? I am using NginX as HTTP server

Comment: One, can you just make the directory manually? Two, check the permissions of the user/group that PHP is running as. Three, try running the jar with `—help` or similar to see if you can specify a cache folder that you can control.

Comment: Hello @ChrisHaas You are right. I created the directory manually. As soon as given proper permission to that directory the `exec() via PHP` working pefectly. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fixed the issue with help of the comment by @ChrisHaas The actual issue was related to proper permission to www-data (Apache2) to access the directory. I given permission to the directory like -

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/selenium-drivers`

and then I can execute the command

```
<?php
$cmd = "java -jar /var/www/html/selenium-drivers/selenium-server-4.14.1.jar node --port 5555 --selenium-manager true";
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
?>
```

Comment: Great you solved the problem (don't forget to [accept/upvote your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so futuer visitors can see it is helpful).  Note though that [using 777 permissions is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271596/how-will-a-server-become-vulnerable-with-chmod-777), you should not do that.  The user that is running the web server is the one that needs write permission, correct?  So only that user needs write permissions.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks